# Record cassettes using computer

Tags: mp3, recording, stereo, analog, gear

I know there are a lot of devices that take cassettes and digitize them into MP3s, but I'm looking to do the opposite. I'm looking for a device that I can plug my computer's (or phone or whatever) headphone jack into and record a cassette tape off of that line in. Most cassette recorders I've found can only record off of AM/FM or through a mono mic line. I'm looking for one that has a stereo aux line in and can record passably good quality music onto a cassette.

Comment: "Most cassette recorders I've found can only record off of AM/FM or through a mono mic line" . Then you must be looking at voice recorders, or radios that happen to have a cassette player in it.

Answer (score 2):

Use any decent quality tape deck.  Stereo recording tape decks are [quite common](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=stereo%20tape%20deck%20recorder).